# Do herbs grow back?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

There are Survival Challenges that require you to collect a certain amount of a specific herb. I'd like to complete these challenges, but I'm wondering if collecting the herbs when my health is full is a good idea. If they don't grow back I'm wasting a lot of healing potential that I might need later.

So, do the herbs grow back? And if they do, any idea on the timeframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do grow back. They grow back when you fast travel or advance time. 
Because they're the only healing item it would be very annoying if they did not grow back.

Comment: [Here's a screenshot confirming that they do respawn, at least when you wait](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaggv.jpg)